# python script in cronjob not writing stdout to files

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script which runs fine when started from a normal shell.  The end result of the script is to run some commands using `subprocess` and write the output to many files  When running via cron, the script runs but the files are never created, i know it runs since it logs some output to syslog, but i cant seem to make cron write to the files.

Here is the cron setup:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 14 * * * echo 'source ~/venv/python3.8/bin/activate; python ~/scripts/myscript.py' | /bin/bash
```

Relevant part of the script:

```
for line in mylist:
    cmd = f"/usr/local/bin/bgpq3 -J -A -z {line}"
    filename = f"{line}.txt"
    logging.debug(f"Running {cmd}")
    ret = subprocess.run(
        cmd, shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    if ret.returncode == 0:
        f = open(filename, "w")
        f.write(ret.stdout)
        f.close()
    else:
        print(ret.stderr)
        logging.info(f"{ret.stderr} {line}")
```

The result could be many files created depending on the list.  Like i said, this all works perfectly when kicked off from a normal shell, and the script runs when started with cron, but the files are never created / written.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lol nevermind.  It was writing the files to my home directory.  I was expecting them to be in the same directory that i was running the script from